# Form Doesn't Validate and there are No Errors. CSRF Token Included

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I am working on a flask app with a few flask wtforms. When I get the forms they are never validated, yet the form errors are empty. What might be my issue?

One common issue I know I don't have is including the csrf_token. I included it and can see it's rendered in the html when my webpage loads. But none the less there is no validation

This is my html file being rendered

```html
<div class="forms center">
    <h1>Account Details</h1>
    <h2>Update Email Address</h2>
    <form id="update-email" action={{ url_for('crud.update_email') }} method="post">
        {{ email_form.hidden_tag() }}
        <div><input type="text" name="new-email" placeholder="new email address" value=""></div>
        <div><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update Email Address"></div>
    </form>
    <h2>Update Password</h2>
    <form id="update-password" action={{ url_for('crud.update_password') }} method="post">
        {{ password_form.hidden_tag() }}
        <div><input type="password" name="old-password" placeholder="enter old password" id="old-password" value=""></div>
        <div><input type="password" name="new-password" placeholder="enter new password" id="new-password" value=""></div>
        <div><input type="password" name="retypepassword" placeholder="retype password" id="retypepassword" value=""></div>
        <div><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Update Password"></div>
    </form>
</div>
```

And it is being rendered in this route

```py
@views.route('/account-details', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
@login_required
def account_details():
    email_form = UpdateEmailForm()
    password_form = UpdatePasswordForm()
    return render_template('account-details.html', email_form=email_form, password_form=password_form)
```

The submit of the update password form goes to here

```py
@crud.route('/update-password', methods=['POST'])
def update_password():
    form = UpdatePasswordForm()
    old_password = request.form.get('old-password')
    new_password = pbkdf2_sha256.hash(request.form.get('new-password'))
    userid = session.get('userid')
    user_dao = UserDao()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user_dao.update_password(userid, new_password)
        return jsonify({"success": True})
    return jsonify({"success": False})
```

Here is the form class I am using

```py
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, validators
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Email, EqualTo, Length, ValidationError

class UpdatePasswordForm(FlaskForm):
    oldpassword = PasswordField('old-password', [DataRequired()])
    newpassword = PasswordField('new-password', [DataRequired(), EqualTo('retypepassword'), Length(min=6)])
    retypepassword = PasswordField('retypepassword', [DataRequired()])
```

Looking at the network tab in the browser it is sending the expected results in the post request and if I check on the back end it is receiving everything as expected. Unfortunately the form doesn't validate anyway and for this reason I expect it has to do with something I don't understand about wtforms

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe the alternative answer to be correct. I have many FlaskForms where I do not pass the request.

Instead I think your error might be in your naming convention. Your Class field names are:

```
'oldpassword' 'newpassword' etc..
```

but your HTML element ids and names are:

```
'old-password' 'new-password'
```

I.e. the form does not know what to parse. Align your names..

Comment: Thanks very much! This worked, although I couldn't have: ```python old-password``` or anything else on the left sign of ```=``` because it took the minus sign as an operator. So I just changed the name in my html file to not have a '-'. I didn't find anywhere in the docs that these things must match. Maybe I will look into getting that written down. Anyway thanks again for the help

Answer (score 1):

In your POST, you need to pass the request data into the form:

```
form = UpdatePasswordForm(request.POST)
```

You won't need to get values from the `request.form` and you can validate before doing updates:

```
@crud.route('/update-password', methods=['POST'])
def update_password():
    form = UpdatePasswordForm(request.POST)

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        userid = session.get('userid')
        user_dao = UserDao()

        new_password = pbkdf2_sha256.hash(form.newpassword.data)
        user_dao.update_password(userid, new_password)
        return jsonify({"success": True})
    return jsonify({"success": False})
```

Edit: I would highly recommend reading the [WTForms crash course](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/stable/crash_course.html) (and more) to get a good idea of what WTForms can do - it's very useful.

Comment: Just to clarify are you using flask-wtf or just wtforms? I ask because the link you gave is to just wtforms and I am not sure how this differs form flask-wtf. It still seems to be not validating for me. Is there something obvious I'm missing other than passing the request form to the Form object?